# tikzpicture side by side is not working for pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats

I need to align my graphs side by side. I tried with \qquad and \hspace but it's not working for both of them. Below is the code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]  
\centering 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend pos=south east, ylabel = NCD, ymin=0,ymax=1, xlabel = Relative execution time, xmin=1, xmax=10, xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},]
    \addplot[
        scatter,only marks,scatter src=explicit symbolic,
        scatter/classes={
            ModExp={mark=square*,black},
            MulMod16={mark=square*,red},
           % AES={mark=o,draw=black,fill=white}
             AES={mark=square*,green},
             SHA={mark=square*,yellow},
             blowfish={mark=square*,brown},
             MD5={mark=square*,cyan}
        }
    ]
    table[x=x,y=y,meta=label]{
        x    y    label
        1.393  0.6248 ModExp
        3.348 0.7095 MulMod16
        1.503 0.663451 AES
        2.57 0.63203  SHA
        1.581  0.6059  blowfish
        9.3  0.7613  MD5
           };
    \legend{ModExp,MulMod16,AES,SHA,blowfish,MD5 }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend pos=south east, ylabel = NCD, ymin=0,ymax=1, xlabel = Relative execution time, xmin=1, xmax=10, xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},]
    \addplot[
        scatter,only marks,scatter src=explicit symbolic,
        scatter/classes={
            ModExp={mark=square*,black},
            MulMod16={mark=square*,red},
           % AES={mark=o,draw=black,fill=white}
             AES={mark=square*,green},
             SHA={mark=square*,yellow},
             blowfish={mark=square*,brown},
             MD5={mark=square*,cyan}
        }
    ]
    table[x=x,y=y,meta=label]{
        x    y    label
        1.393  0.6248 ModExp
        3.348 0.7095 MulMod16
        1.503 0.663451 AES
        2.57 0.63203  SHA
        1.581  0.6059  blowfish
        9.3  0.7613  MD5
           };
    \legend{ModExp,MulMod16,AES,SHA,blowfish,MD5 }
\end{axis}
%%\caption{Plot of execution time and NCD value for a random/unintelligible application of obfuscation transformation function -sub, -bcf, -split\_num=7}
%\label{fig:cp}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please add the document preamble?

Comment: Sorry. It's added now.

Comment: If you add % right after the first `\end{tikzpicture}`, but the whole thing is too wide, I think. Consider making the plots smaller.

Comment: If you add `\hspace*{-2.8cm}` before the first `\begin{tikzpicture}` you get something that looks sort of acceptable. But don't tell anyone that you got this from me ;-) (BTW, the caption and label need to go *after* the last `\end{tikzpicture}` but before `\end{tikzpicture}`.)

Comment: Thanks, @marmot. Hahaha. Sure, I'll not tell anyone.

Answer (score 1):

- your diagrams are to wide that can be placed in one line. reduce their widths to `0.5\linewidth`
- caption should be outside of `tikzpicture` environment

**edit:**

according to comments below i change the code as follows:
- move common option to `\pgfplotsset` for this figure
- added is `legend style`
- defined is diagram height
considering aforementioned the code is much shorter and legend doesn't cover marks in diagrams anymore. is now better?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h¸tb]
    \pgfplotsset{width=0.5\linewidth,
                 height=0.5\linewidth,
                 ylabel = NCD,
                 ymin=0,ymax=1,
                 xlabel = Relative execution time,
                 xmin=1, xmax=10,
                 xtick={1,2,...,10},
                 scatter,
                 scatter src=explicit symbolic,
                 scatter/classes={
                    ModExp={mark=square*,black},
                    MulMod16={mark=square*,red},
                    AES={mark=square*,green},
                    SHA={mark=square*,yellow},
                    blowfish={mark=square*,brown},
                    MD5={mark=square*,cyan}
                         },
                 legend style={
                 font=\small,
                 cells={anchor=west},
                 legend pos=outer north east,
                 legend pos=south east},
                }% end of pgfplotsset
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot[only marks]
    table[x=x,y=y,meta=label]{
        x    y    label
        1.393  0.6248   ModExp
        3.348  0.7095   MulMod16
        1.503  0.663451 AES
        2.57   0.63203  SHA
        1.581  0.6059   blowfish
        9.3  0.7613     MD5
           };
    \legend{ModExp,MulMod16,AES,SHA,blowfish,MD5}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot[only marks]
    table[x=x,y=y,meta=label]{
        x    y    label
        1.393  0.6248   ModExp
        3.348  0.7095   MulMod16
        1.503  0.663451 AES
        2.57   0.63203  SHA
        1.581  0.6059   blowfish
        9.3  0.7613     MD5
           };
    \legend{ModExp,MulMod16,AES,SHA,blowfish,MD5}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Plot of execution time and NCD value for a random/unintelligible application of obfuscation transformation function -sub, -bcf, -split\_num=7}
\label{fig:cp}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. But the legend is masking my MD5 point (blue box is covered by legend).

Comment: i didn't check/bother with this. it can be repair with `legend style`.  i will add this as well improve somehow your code soon.